# Client crashes with 3221225725 error

Tags: c++, server, client, segmentation-fault

This code contacts a server on my computer and sends packets to it (the server/client connection is fine). After the program loops for a number of times, it crashes with a SIGSEGV segmentation fault. I can't figure how to stop the crash from happening. 
I just recently started working with clients/servers, and I retrieved the code from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591(v=vs.85).aspx

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
    #define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
    #define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"
int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv) {
WSADATA wsaData;
SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                *ptr = NULL,
                hints;
char *sendbuf = "this is a test";
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int iResult;
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

// Validate the parameters
/*if (argc != 2) {
    printf("usage: %s server-name\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
}*/

// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}

ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

// Resolve the server address and port
iResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
if ( iResult != 0 ) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, 
        ptr->ai_protocol);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        continue;
    }
    break;
}

freeaddrinfo(result);

if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Send an initial buffer
iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

// shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Receive until the peer closes the connection
do {

    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if ( iResult > 0 )
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
    else if ( iResult == 0 )
        printf("Connection closed\n");
    else
        printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

} while( iResult > 0 );

// cleanup
closesocket(ConnectSocket);
WSACleanup();

return main(argc,argv);
}
```

Comment: And when you used a debugger to run your code, what was the reason the debugger gave you for the segfault, and what was the backtrace?

Comment: The backtrace was:
printf(__format = 0x47514c "Bytes received: %d\n") c:/users/nick/desktop/desktop files/programming stuff/c++/coding programs/dev-cpp/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/stdio.h 256
(It brought me to stdio.h)
--
The other is in my main function: 
It brought me to: printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);

Comment: @newbcoder `return main(argc,argv);`  What??  Why are you calling `main`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: From *inside* main - so I wonder if the OP has infinite recursion.

Comment: It's not even legal C++ to call `main` directly.

Comment: So, should I return back to another function if I want the program not exit?
Instead of using return main.

Comment: Have you tried a loop in your `main` function?

Comment: No, you write another loop. Yes, that's what's happening -- you're blowing out your stack.

Comment: I just tried a loop in the main function. Thank you. I believe the problem is fixed.